# How to unit test spring mvc interceptors without controller class

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc

I am trying to write a unit test for one of the interceptors in my spring-mvc rest application. I am using:

```
- TestNG 6.8.7
- Mockito 1.9.5
- Spring 4.0.0
```

Is it mandatory to have controllers to unit test the interceptors? Can we write a unit test without writing controller?

Thanks,NN

Comment: can you show how you used `MockMvc` to test your interceptor ?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you mean `HandlerInterceptor`,

> Is it mandatory to have controllers to unit test the interceptors?

No. A unit test is meant to be as self contained as possible. If you're unit testing the `HandlerInterceptor` implementation, the only things involved are your implementation and all of its dependencies.

> Can we write a unit test without writing controller?

Yes. [`HandlerInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) is just an interface with three (3) methods. None of those methods *require* a controller, so you don't *need* a controller.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it mandatory to have controllers to unit test the interceptors?

**No. Its not!**

> Can we write a unit test without writing controller?

**Yes. You can!**, as shown below.

1. Setup a web application context.
2. Get handler mapping bean.
3. Get handler execution chain.
4. Iterate over interceptors and call `preHandle` method.
5. Call controller's `handleRequest` method.
6. Tterate over interceptors and call `postHandle` method.

   protected void setUp() throws Exception {
           super.setUp();

   ```
       String[] configFiles = new String[] {
               "file:///c:/abc.xml",
                };

       /*
        * Ref: http://www.koders.com/java/fid78745323A147B238F4B366225C31603C6F87CE75.aspx?s=%22Seth+Ladd%22
        */
       MockServletContext sctx = new MockServletContext("");
       ctx = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
       ctx.setServletContext(sctx);

       ctx.setConfigLocations(configFiles);
       ctx.refresh();
   }

   private void testRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){

       try {
           MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest("GET","/urlpath/soemname");
           MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();

           request.setServerName("www.domainname.com");

           HandlerMapping handlerMapping = (HandlerMapping) this.getCtx().getBean("beanname");

           HandlerExecutionChain hec = handlerMapping.getHandler(request);
           Controller handler = (Controller) hec.getHandler();

           HandlerInterceptor interceptors[] = hec.getInterceptors();

           /*
            * Calling preHandle on interceptors
            */
           for(int i=0; i < interceptors.length; i++){

               interceptors[i].preHandle(request, response, handler);
           }

           /*
            * calling the controller handleRequest
            */
           ModelAndView modelAndView = handler.handleRequest(request, response);

           /*
            * Calling postHandle on interceptors
            */
           for(int i=0; i < interceptors.length; i++){
               interceptors[i].postHandle(request, response, handler, modelAndView);
           }

           /*
            * Validating the response
            */

       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           fail();
       }
   }
   ```

Source: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/43787-testing-handlerinterceptors-and-controllers

Shishir

Comment: Careful, your example is not a unit testing. It is an integration test.

Comment: Oh! I am sorry, I didn't realize that. Although the process will remain same, I will post the correct sample code. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I also noticed that now. This is no unit testing. My first question was `Is it mandatory to have controllers to unit test the interceptors?` and everybody here answered `NO` and yet, in the example and the forum link, they are calling `ModelAndView modelAndView = handler.handleRequest(request, response);` to test the interceptor. This is as good as writing a unit test for a controller using `MockMvc` which is cleaner and way simpler than this. I am already doing that. All I wanted is a different way to test interceptor in silo. Anyways, I think this thread is closed.

Comment: As @SotiriosDelimanolis said, "If you're unit testing the HandlerInterceptor implementation, the only things involved are your implementation and all of its dependencies" . So you dont need a controller. And as you said , the `MockMvc` approach is better than this example, if you go for integration testing

Comment: Source link is no longer valid.